# Populating QTableWidget with CSV file using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, csv, pyqgis-3, qt-designer

I've managed to populate a QTableWidget with data stored in a database with the code below:

```
self.cur.execute("""SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4 from schema.table WHERE column1 IN ('""" + str(self.dlg.mComboBox.currentText()) + """') AND  column2 >= '""" + str(self.dlg.mDateTimeEdit.dateTime().toString("yyyyMMdd")) + """' AND column2 <= '""" + str(self.dlg.mDateTimeEdit_2.dateTime().toString("yyyyMMdd")) + """' """)

self.dlg.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
self.dlg.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
for row_number, row_data in enumerate(self.cur):
    self.dlg.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
    for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
        self.dlg.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
```

I thought I could easily do the same with CSV data but I'm actually facing issue displaying data from my CSV file into the qtableview.

How can I address this? I haven't been able to solve my problem with the few relative topics I found on StackExchange yet.

Last attempt here:

```
    with open('C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/plugin_test/file.csv', 'rb') as stream:

        self.dlg.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(0)
        self.dlg.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(0)
        for rowdata in csv.reader(stream):
            row = self.dlg.tableWidget_2.rowCount()
            self.dlg.tableWidget_2.insertRow(row)
            self.dlg.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(len(rowdata))
            for column, data in enumerate(rowdata):
                item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data.decode('utf8'))
                self.dlg.tableWidget_2.setItem(row, column, item)
```

With this last code I don't get any warning messages from qgis but nothing happen neither

Comment: Could you mention what is the issue you're facing?

Comment: I don't know how to proceed to insert the data from my csv into the qtablewidget... I've checked at other topics and videos on youtube but none of the solutions provided worked out... I'm still a beginner with python. I've added the last thing I tried to my initial question but the code is completely wrong (I don't get any warning messages from qgis but nothing happen neither)

Comment: I usually set both row and column counts before filling the table widget (for instance, using the length of my lists), and instead of using `insertRow()` I just set items (they are there already when I set the row count). See [this example](https://github.com/SwissTierrasColombia/Asistente-LADM-COL/blob/a786b2d408a7de6c7f53ffa3c44466542c8fe510/asistente_ladm_col/gui/field_data_capture/base_allocate_parcels_initial_panel.py#L90-L114).

Comment: By the way, since this question is about PyQt and has no direct relation with GIS, I suggest you to ask in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code works with an arbitrary CSV created by me.

```
import csv

data = []

with open('/home/zeito/Desktop/data_test/data5.csv', 'r') as stream:
    for rowdata in csv.reader(stream):
        data.append(rowdata)

labels = data[0]

del data[0]

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Dlg(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()

        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1,"Tab1")

        nb_row = len(data)
        nb_col = len(data[0])
        
        self.tab1.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setRowCount(nb_row)
        self.table.setColumnCount(nb_col)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)
        
        for row in range (nb_row):
            for col in range(nb_col):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(str(data[row][col]))
                self.table.setItem(row, col, item)
        
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs, 0, 0)
        
w = Dlg()
w.resize(600,400)
w.setWindowTitle('Populating QTableWidget with CSV file')
w.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
w.show()
```

Content of CSV is as follows:

```
date,temp,hr,ws,ppt
20200901,11.0,15.0,1.0,1.0
20200902,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
20200903,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
20200904,1.0,1.0,30,1.0
20200905,1.0,22.0,1.0,1.0
20200906,14.0,1.0,15.0,1.0
```

After running above code in python console of QGIS, I got following result.

[image]